# How to compare df values with the elements of a list, and make a df with those values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     Name           Object
     
     Patrick        ball
     Patrick        tshirt
     Patrick        headphones          
     Leonard        ball
     Leonard        tshirt
     Leonard        pants
     Leonard        headphones
     Larry          ball
     Larry          headphones
     Larry          tshirt
     Larry          cellphone
     Maria          book
     Maria          cellphone
     Nick           computer
     Nick           ball

objects=['ball','tshirt','headphones','pants','cellphone','book','computer']
```

I want a dataframe with the names of the persons and the missing elements in comparison with the objects list, like this:

```
    Name            Object
    
    Patrick         pants 
    Patrick         cellphone
    Patrick         book
    Patrick         computer
    Leonard         headphones
    Leonard         cellphone
    Leonard         book 
    Leonard         computer
       .               .
       .               .
       .               .
    Nick            tshit
    Nick            headphones
    Nick            pants
    Nick            cellphone
    Nick            book
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `pivot_table` with `any` as aggregate function and `reindex` the column with the list of `objects`. Use `stack` to go back on a Series but without dropping nan (the missing objects) then select the row with `isna` and create the desired dataframe.

```
s = (df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Object', aggfunc=any)
       .reindex(columns=objects)
       .stack(dropna=False)
    )
df_ = s[s.isna()].index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_)
       Name      Object
0   Patrick       pants
1   Patrick   cellphone
2   Patrick        book
3   Patrick    computer
4   Leonard   cellphone
5   Leonard        book
6   Leonard    computer
7     Larry       pants
8     Larry        book
9     Larry    computer
10    Maria        ball
11    Maria      tshirt
12    Maria  headphones
13    Maria       pants
14    Maria    computer
15     Nick      tshirt
16     Nick  headphones
17     Nick       pants
18     Nick   cellphone
19     Nick        book
```

To create `s`, you can also use `set_index` and `reindex` with the `MultiIndex.from_product` based on `unique` element of the column Name and the list `objects`. This method would be interesting if you have other columns in the dataframe, here one need to create a random column with `assign` to do it.

```
s = (df.assign(a=True)
       .set_index(['Name', 'Object'])['a']
       .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Name.unique(), objects], 
                                           names=['Name', 'Object']))
    )
```

Comment: I got an error Ben.T TypeError: Expected tuple, got str. Seems i can't pivot a df table, only tuples to df.

Comment: @Javier what is the result of `df.columns` for you?

Comment: Index(['DZ', 'NOMBRE_ESTACION', 'CODIGO', 'CATEGORIA', 'CLASIFICACION', 'TIPO', 'COMUNICACION', 'FECHA_DE_INSTALACION', 'ULTIMO_REGISTRO',
       'ESTADO_SENAMHI', 'ESTADO_OMM', 'LATITUD', 'LONGITUD', 'ALTITUD',
       'DEPARTAMENTO', 'PROVINCIA', 'DISTRITO', 'REGION_HIDROGRAFICA',
       'UNIDAD_HIDROGRAFICA'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: I have another information but i'm extrapolating your method.

Comment: @Javier yes so it is what I tried ot say with the second method, then if you want the pivot to work, you need to select only the 2 columns like `s = (df[['Name', 'Object']].pivot_table(...` otherwise try the second method with `set_index` maybe

Comment: Now is working,  the second solution gets me a multiindex error but i will check it. Many thanks!!!